# Flask-Sqlalchemy : How to call a function everytime a new instance of a model is commited?

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to make a new randomized user id every time a new user is committed.
For this I am using the format : `USR-<token>`

The token is made by this function :

```
import string
import secrets
def make_token():
    set = string.ascii_letters+string.digits
    while True:
        token = ''.join(secrets.choice(set) for i in range(6))
        if(any(c.islower() for c in token) and
           any(c.isupper() for c in token) and
           sum(c.isdigit() for c in token)>=3 ):
           break
    return token
```

This function will be called in this database model :

```
class User(db.Model):
    usrid = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True,
                        default="USR-{}".format(make_token()))
    usrnm = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable = False)
```

I want the token to be new every time. But right now If I commit two User objects it gives me a `Constraint Failed : Unique` error. Also, I'm using SQLite for testing, if that makes any difference.
The model is bigger than this but for the question I think only these parts are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the `make_token` function AS the `default` argument, instead of its return value.

So you could try having your `make_token` function prepend "USR-" to the string:

```
    # ...
    return "USR-" + token
```

And then pass that function as the `default` argument:

```
    usrid = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True,
                    default=make_token)
```

Comment: Hey that really worked! But I want to use this function in multiple models. Like in an event table : `"EVT-"+make_token` but that doesn't work here :( I'll update the question.

Comment: @WISERDIVISOR I'd mark this as correct, and post a new question based on your modified code.  Otherwise this answer becomes invalid.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask another question. But can you still help here?

Comment: @WISERDIVISOR Why not have a `usr_make_token` function and `other_make_token` function, which both use the `make_token` function to get the ID, but the two specific functions add a particular string to the beginning, each of which is specified as `default` for the required field.

Comment: Or better yet I think I should make a class for making token that has user token object and other token objects. I will do that and come back. Thanks :)

Comment: I A B S O L U T E L Y failed in using a class. But your solution of making 3 functions worked like a charm. Thank you so much @v25 !!!!!